# Why does Kohana use before() and after()

Tags: php, kohana

I've just started having a play with Kohana, coming from CodeIgniter and straight php. I was wondering why Kohana uses the `before()` and `after()` functions rather than normal constructors and destructors?

Comment: Because doing so allows a greater level of control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between the 2:

The `constructor` and `destructor` are called when an instance is created and destroyed.

The `before` and `after` methods are called before and after an action of a controller is executed.

Besides that, you can't guarantee the `constructor` and `destructor` are called before and after the action is executed, but you can guarantee that for the `before` and `after` methods.

Comment: Unless your application is not unrecoverable broken the destructor is garantueed. On the other hand `after()` is not called too, when the app is broken before it is called.

Comment: I guess I meant you can't guarantee the constructor/destructor being called before/after the execution of the action. I'll change this a bit to clarify more what I meant.

Comment: It's also guaranteed, that the constructor is called before `before()` and the destructor is called after `after()` :D But I think I can imagine, what you mean: You have less till no control on _when_ `__destruct()` gets called. However, I upvoted already, anyway, because the interesting parts are clarified.

Comment: That was my point exactly: you have no control over exactly when the constructor and destructor are being called. Before and after are called directly before and after the action :)

Comment: Also, the parameter list for the constructor has changed since 3.0 but I assume the before method won't ever have parameters. Some people had issues when upgrading which they could have avoided by using the before method.

Comment: @Darsstar: optimistic assumption :) As I see the Kohana team is pretty radical in upgrades. It wouldn't surprise me much if everything changed in the next version :)